# Upload file in Laravel - wrong path

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

I am beginner in Laravel.
I have this code:

```
if ($request->hasfile('profilePhoto')) {
            $this->validate($request, [
                'profilePhoto' => 'required',
                'profilePhoto.*' => 'mimetypes:image/jpg'
            ]);
            $image = $request->file('profilePhoto');
            $extension = strtolower($image->getClientOriginalExtension());
            $path = 'upload/images/UserImage/';
            $uniqueName = md5($image . time());
            $image->move(public_path($path), $uniqueName . '.' . $extension);
        }
```

This function uploads files to `public/upload/images/UserImage/`.
I need it to store it in `storage/app/upload/images/UserImage/` instead

How can I rewrite my code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to use `storage_path` function ("storage/app/upload" folder must exist):

```
$image->move(storage_path("app/upload"), $uniqueName . '.' . $extension);
```

Comment: Thx. When I open url in my browser: http://domain.test/storage/file.jpg - I have error 404. File is exist in storage. I have laradock and I make symlink

Comment: Let me understand. Now is it another problem? Did the upload work?

Answer (score 0):

```php
if ($request->hasfile('profilePhoto')) {
        $this->validate($request, [
              'profilePhoto' => 'required',
              'profilePhoto.*' => 'mimetypes:image/jpg'
        ]);
        $image = $request->file('profilePhoto');
        $extension = strtolower($image->getClientOriginalExtension());
        $path = storage_path('app/public/upload/images/UserImage');
        $uniqueName = md5($image . time());
        $image->move(public_path($path), $uniqueName . '.' . $extension);
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

A common way in Laravel to upload to `storage/app` is through the local disk driver.

```
$file = $path . $uniqueName . '.' . $extension;
\Storage::disk('local')->put($file, $request->file('profilePhoto'));
```

`Storage::disk('local')` points to `storage/app/`.

Answer (score 0):

As your $path variable is already declared like this `$path = 'upload/images/UserImage/'` .So instead of storing data to `public_path` you can store to `storage_path()`.

`$image->move(storage_path($path), $uniqueName . '.' . $extension);`